# Xamarin Android drawn bitmaps in grid view causes slow and choppy scrolling

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-canvas, android-gridview

I am building an Android application, using the Xamarin framework, that displays profile photos for users. The photos may either be drawn within an oval, like you'd see on any social network, or in a rectangle based on what screen the user is on. The images I am drawing are downloaded from a web service and may be any size. Thus I must scale the photos, fix any rotation issues, and then draw them either in a rectangle or an oval.

The entire process I have works fine, but the problem I have is when I load several of the profile views into a grid view, then the performance of the scroll event becomes very choppy and slow. I also get warnings in the console saying that 30 frames have been skipped, and that I may be doing to much on the main thread.

To try and fix the issue I've pushed the loading of the images to a background task, and that is also working great. However, the actual onDraw event is drawn on the main thread as it's drawn by the OS.

I've tracked down the issue to the canvas.drawBitmap() function call. When I comment out this command then the slow scrolling issues goes away, and I no longer get the warnings in the logs. This tells me that my process is efficient enough without the draw command, but when I add the draw command I start to get performance issues.

Does anyone know how I can optimize the drawing process so that I can achieve smooth scrolling? My code is below.

This is my grid view adapter class that loads the profile photo views...

```
namespace AndroidApp
{
    public class GridViewAdapter : ArrayAdapter<UserContact>
    {
        private Activity ParentActivity;

        #region Interface

        public interface GridViewAdapterCallback
        {
            void DidSelectRow(Conversation conversation);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Initialization

        private int LayoutResourceId;
        private List<UserContact> Data = null;

        public GridViewAdapterCallback callback;

        public GridViewAdapter (Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<UserContact> data, Activity parentActivity) : base (context, layoutResourceId, data)
        {
            this.LayoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.Data = data;
            this.ParentActivity = parentActivity;
        }

        public void SetData (List<UserContact> data)
        {
            this.Data = data;
        }

        #endregion

        #region List Delegates

        public override Android.Views.View GetView (int position, Android.Views.View convertView, Android.Views.ViewGroup parent)
        {
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.From (this.Context);
                convertView = inflater.Inflate(this.LayoutResourceId, parent, false);
            }

            UserContact row = this.Data[position];
            this.SetContactToGridItem (convertView, row);

            return convertView;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Setters

        private void SetContactToGridItem (Android.Views.View view, UserContact contact)
        {
            // get view references
            ProfileImageView imageView = view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.profileImageView).JavaCast<ProfileImageView>();
            imageView.ProfileImageViewStyle = ProfileImageViewStyle.Square;
            imageView.ResetImage ();
            imageView.SetContact (contact, this.ParentActivity);

            TextView textView = (TextView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.textView);
            textView.SetText (contact.GetFullName (), TextView.BufferType.Normal);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

This is my main profile view class...

```
namespace AndroidApp
{
    public enum ProfileImageViewColor
    {
        Default = 0,
        White = 1
    };

    public enum ProfileImageViewStyle
    {
        Default = 0,
        Square = 1
    };

    public class ProfileImageView : ImageView
    {
        public ProfileImageViewColor ProfileImageViewColor { get; set; }
        public ProfileImageViewStyle ProfileImageViewStyle { get; set; }

        private User User { get; set; }
        private UserContact Contact { get; set; }
        Bitmap Bitmap;
        private Activity Activity { get; set; }

        public ProfileImageView (System.IntPtr intPtr, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership owner) : base (intPtr, owner)
        {
            Initialize ();
        }

        public ProfileImageView (Context context) : base (context)
        {
            Initialize ();
        }

        public ProfileImageView (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base (context, attrs)
        {
            Initialize ();
        }

        public ProfileImageView (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base (context, attrs, defStyle)
        {
            Initialize ();
        }

        void Initialize ()
        {
            this.ProfileImageViewColor = ProfileImageViewColor.Default;
            this.ProfileImageViewStyle = ProfileImageViewStyle.Default;
            this.SetScaleType (ScaleType.FitCenter);
            this.CropToPadding = true;
        }

        #region Setters

        public void SetUser (User user, Activity activity)
        {
            this.User = user;
            this.Activity = activity;

            if (this.User != null)
            {
                byte[] imageData = this.User.GetProfilePhoto ();

                if (imageData != null)
                {
                    this.SetImageData (this.User.GetProfilePhotoPath (), imageData);
                }
                else
                {
                    UserBusiness.GetUserPhoto (this.User, (Shared.Error error, User usr) => {
                        activity.RunOnUiThread (() => {
                            this.SetImageData (this.User.GetProfilePhotoPath (), this.User.GetProfilePhoto ());
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        public void SetContact (UserContact contact, Activity activity)
        {
            this.Contact = contact;
            this.Activity = activity;

            if (this.Contact != null)
            {
                byte[] imageData = this.Contact.GetProfilePhoto();

                if (imageData != null)
                {
                    this.SetImageData (this.Contact.GetProfilePhotoPath (), imageData);
                }
                else
                {
                    UserContactPhotoDownloadManager.CreateManager ().DownloadProfilePhoto (contact, (Shared.Error error, UserContact userContact) => {
                        activity.RunOnUiThread (() => {
                            this.SetImageData (this.Contact.GetProfilePhotoPath (), this.Contact.GetProfilePhoto ());
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        public override void SetImageBitmap (Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            if (bitmap == null)
            {
                this.SetImageResource (this.GetDefaultProfileImageID ());
            }
            else
            {
                ProfileImageDrawable drawable = new ProfileImageDrawable (bitmap, this.Width, this.Height, this.ProfileImageViewStyle);
                this.SetImageDrawable (drawable);
            }
        }

        public void ResetImage ()
        {
            if (this.Bitmap != null)
                this.Bitmap.Recycle ();

            this.SetImageBitmap (null);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Private

        private void SetImageData (byte[] imageData)
        {
            if (this.Bitmap != null)
            {
                this.Bitmap.Recycle ();
                this.Bitmap = null;
            }

            if (imageData == null)
            {
                this.SetImageResource (this.GetDefaultProfileImageID ());
            }
            else
            {
                this.Bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray (imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
                ProfileImageDrawable drawable = new ProfileImageDrawable (this.Bitmap, this.Width, this.Height, this.ProfileImageViewStyle);
                this.SetImageDrawable (drawable);
            }
        }

        private void SetImageData (string filePath, byte[] imageData)
        {
            if (this.Bitmap != null)
            {
                this.Bitmap.Recycle ();
                this.Bitmap = null;
            }

            if (imageData == null)
            {
                this.SetImageResource (this.GetDefaultProfileImageID ());
            }
            else
            {
                this.SetImageAsync (filePath);
            }
        }

        private void SetImageAsync (string filePath)
        {
            ImageDrawTask task = new ImageDrawTask (filePath, this, (Drawable drawable) => {
                this.Activity.RunOnUiThread (() => {
                    this.SetImageDrawable (drawable);
                });
            });
            task.Execute ();
        }

        private int GetDefaultProfileImageID ()
        {
            if (this.ProfileImageViewColor == ProfileImageViewColor.Default)
                return (int)typeof (Resource.Drawable).GetField ("profile_image_placeholder").GetValue (null);
            else
                return (int)typeof (Resource.Drawable).GetField ("profile_image_placeholder_white").GetValue (null);
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class ImageDrawTask: AsyncTask {

        public delegate void ImageDrawTaskCompletion (Drawable drawable);

        private string FilePath;
        private ProfileImageView ImageView;
        private ImageDrawTaskCompletion Completion;

        public ImageDrawTask (string filePath, ProfileImageView imageView, ImageDrawTaskCompletion completion)
        {
            this.FilePath = filePath;
            this.ImageView = imageView;
            this.Completion = completion;
        }

        protected override void OnPreExecute()
        {
        }

        protected override Java.Lang.Object DoInBackground(params Java.Lang.Object[] @params)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = ImageUtilities.FixRotation (this.FilePath);
            ProfileImageDrawable drawable = new ProfileImageDrawable (bitmap, this.ImageView.Width, this.ImageView.Height, this.ImageView.ProfileImageViewStyle);
            Completion (drawable);
            return null;
        }

        protected override void OnPostExecute(Java.Lang.Object result)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And finally here is my drawable class...

```
namespace AndroidApp
{
    public class ProfileImageDrawable : Drawable
    {
        Bitmap Bitmap;
        ProfileImageViewStyle Style;
        int Width;
        int Height;

        private RectF DrawFrame;

        public ProfileImageDrawable (Bitmap bmp, int width, int height, ProfileImageViewStyle style)
        {
            this.Bitmap = bmp;
            this.Style = style;
            this.DrawFrame = new RectF ();
            this.Width = width;
            this.Height = height;
        }

        public override void Draw (Canvas canvas)
        {
            if (this.Style == ProfileImageViewStyle.Square)
            {
                canvas.DrawBitmap (this.Bitmap, this.GetMatrix (this.Bitmap, this.Width, this.Height), null);
            }
            else
            {
                BitmapShader bmpShader = new BitmapShader (this.Bitmap, Shader.TileMode.Clamp, Shader.TileMode.Clamp);
                bmpShader.SetLocalMatrix (this.GetMatrix (this.Bitmap, this.Width, this.Height));

                Paint paint = new Paint () { AntiAlias = true, Dither = true };
                paint.SetShader (bmpShader);

                canvas.DrawOval (this.DrawFrame, paint);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnBoundsChange (Rect bounds)
        {
            base.OnBoundsChange (bounds);
            this.DrawFrame.Set (0, 0, bounds.Width (), bounds.Height ());
        }

        public override int IntrinsicWidth {
            get {
                return this.Width;
            }
        }

        public override int IntrinsicHeight {
            get {
                return this.Height;
            }
        }

        public override void SetAlpha (int alpha)
        {

        }

        public override int Opacity {
            get {
                return (int)Format.Opaque;
            }
        }

        public override void SetColorFilter (ColorFilter cf)
        {

        }

        private Matrix GetMatrix (Bitmap bmp, int width, int height)
        {
            Matrix mtx = new Matrix ();

            float scaleWidth = ((float) width) / bmp.Width;
            float scaleHeight = ((float) height) / bmp.Height;
            float newWidth = 0;
            float newHeight = 0;

            if (scaleWidth > scaleHeight) 
            {
                mtx.PostScale (scaleWidth, scaleWidth);
                newWidth = scaleWidth * bmp.Width;
                newHeight = scaleWidth * bmp.Height;
            }
            else
            {
                mtx.PostScale (scaleHeight, scaleHeight);
                newWidth = scaleHeight * bmp.Width;
                newHeight = scaleHeight * bmp.Height;
            }

            mtx.PostTranslate ((width - newWidth) / 2, (height - newHeight) / 2);

            return mtx;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A quick optimisation; `Draw` is called very frequently so move the `new`s of `BitmapShader`, `Paint` and `Bitmap` into the class scope. That will prevent unnecessary heap allocations in the drawing loop. You'll need to reset the matrix in `GetMatrix` by setting it to Identity.

Comment: Yes, I had it defined in the class constructor, but moved it to draw because I wanted to see if that was causing any of the delay. In the examples I'm running that code isn't ran at all because I'm setting the style property to ProfileImageViewStyle.Square, so only the canvas.DrawBitmap... is being called.